# How to merge Arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How to merge many Arrays in php

```
    $array1="Array ( [0] => mouse ) Array ( [0] => mac ) Array ( [0] => keyboard )";
```

how i can array like this

```
    Array( [0] =>mouse  [1] => mac [2] =>keyboard );
```

Comment: Are the arrays stored in a string? As in you got a print_r of 3 arrays from somewhere else and just put them inside a string expecting to get the arrays back?

Comment: `How to merge Arrays` -- wait, that's not an array.

Comment: $array1 = array('mouse', 'mac', 'keyboard');

Comment: i want merge $array1's arrays

Answer (score 1):

depending on how your arrays are being stored, there are a couple of options.

Here are 2 examples:

```
<?php
$old_array = array(
    array('mouse'),
    array('mac'),
    array('keyboard')
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $a){
    $new_array[] = $a[0];
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($new_array),'</pre>';

//// OR ////

$array1 = array('mouse');
$array2 = array('mac');
$array3 = array('keyboard');

$new_array = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);


echo '<pre>',print_r($new_array),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `array_merge` function of PHP.

This:

```
<?php
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

will return this:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```

It's as easy as a piece of cake! :)

Try it: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_merge

Tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: but i want to merge $array1="Array ( [0] => mouse ) Array ( [0] => mac ) Array ( [0] => keyboard )"; not $array1 and $array2

Answer (score 1):

So you basically have an array of arrays. You can do this in the following way:

```
$array = array(array(0 => 'mouse'), array(1 => 'mac'), array(2 => 'keyboard'));

$mergedArray = array();
foreach ($array as $part) {
    $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $part);
}

var_dump($mergedArray);
```

The result is exactly what you would expect:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "mouse"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "mac"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "keyboard"
}
```

If you also have scalars in the big array, you can modify the loop to the following:

```
foreach ($array as $part) {
    if (!is_array($part)) {
        $mergedArray[] = $part;
    } else {
        $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $part);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will merge all values from all sub arrays, it's not limited to one entry per sub array.

Answer (score 0):

php array_merge() function, Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
Merge N number of array using $array = array_merge( $array1 , $array2, $array3 ..... $arrayN);

```
     $array1 = array ( '0' => 'mouse' );
     $array2 = array ( '0' => 'mac' );
     $array3 = array ( '0' => 'keyboard' );
     
     $array = array_merge( $array1 , $array2, $array3);
     
     echo "<pre>";
         print_r($array);
     echo "</pre>";
```

O/P:

```
Array
(
   [0] => mouse
   [1] => mac
   [2] => keyboard
 )
```

More info: https://www.php.net/array_merge

Comment: but i want to merge $array1="Array ( [0] => mouse ) Array ( [0] => mac ) Array ( [0] => keyboard )"; this not $array1 and $array2

Comment: but your mentioned one is not an array, it is string. you can verify that using is_array() function.